# How to generate all possible 2D arrays where 0s are replaced with predetermined values in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, combinations

I'm trying to generate grids using a 'skeleton grid' and then filling in the 0s in this skeleton grid using 'values_to_fill'.

Example will help clear it up.

Input:

> ```
> grid = [[0,2,0,0,0],
>        [2,0,0,0,0],
>        [0,0,4,0,0],
>        [0,0,0,3,5],
>        [0,0,0,0,0]]
>
> values_to_fill = {
>                   1:[1,2],
>                   2:[4,5],
>                   3:[1,3],
>                   4:[7],
>                   5:[[4,7,6]]
>               }
> # 1:[1,2] means: In line 1, fill 0s with a 1 and a 2.
> ```

Output:

> ```
> [[1,2,2,0,0],
>  [2,4,5,0,0],
>  [1,3,4,0,0],
>  [7,0,0,3,5],
>  [4,7,6,0,0]]
>
> [[1,2,0,2,0],
>  [2,4,5,0,0],
>  [1,3,4,0,0],
>  [7,0,0,3,5],
>  [4,7,6,0,0]]
>
> [[1,2,0,0,2],
>  [2,4,5,0,0],
>  [1,3,4,0,0],
>  [7,0,0,3,5],
>  [4,7,6,0,0]]
>
>    and so on and so on...
> ```

For context, this is part of me trying to solve this month's [Jane Street Puzzle. (December 2020)](https://www.janestreet.com/puzzles/current-puzzle/) Part of my attempt is to solve it on pen and paper as far as I can, and then trying to get a computer to brute force the rest. I've got pretty much all the other code working, but I've been wracking my head about this section for 3-4 days now and I feel like it is one too layer too deep for me and I keep hitting a mental wall.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:

The function I am trying to create:

> ```
>  def grid_gen(grid, values_to_fill):
>
>      for count, numbers in enumerate(values_to_fill):
>      ''' E.g. count=3, numbers=[1,3]'''
>
>           # Replace the 0s in grid[count+1] with numbers
>
>      yield grid
> ```

But I can't help but feel that the above approach will not begin to capture all the possibilities.. I need to add another for loop somewhere perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide some code please?

Comment: @music_junkie done! It is not much but I have put where I am at. I am genuinely quite stuck on how to approach this.